# How to implement cache for images using .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching

I want to cache my images and found something like this

`<cache enabled="true">
    Current Time Inside Cache Tag Helper: @DateTime.Now
</cache>`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/cache-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1
How can I implement my image on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cache css,js or images files to asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706370/how-to-cache-css-js-or-images-files-to-asp-net-core)

Comment: You can give it a try with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38786447/9071943)

Comment: Your question is unclear. The `cache` tag helper is for caching bits of HTML (presumably generated by Razor code where the compilation times would be higher than desired). It's not going to cause an actual image file to be cached client-side; that's not what it's for. For that, you need to set `Cache-Control` headers on the image responses. If you're serving via the static files middleware, you can configure the cache headers with that middleware.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - Loved you in Jurrasic park and Guardians of the Galaxy. Keep up the good work!

Comment: @TraeMoore LMFAO, how many times a day you think Chris hears that?  (I went to school with 2 mike jones lol)

Answer (score 1):

Caching for images is client cache and you should configure your app like below:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                ServeUnknownFileTypes = false,
                OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                {
                    const int durationInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24;
                    ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
                    ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.Expires] = new[] { DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1).ToString("R") }; // Format RFC1123
                }
            });
```